# What is the name for the long dashes that sometimes replace the inner letters of a name?

Tags: typography, print-design, typesetting, character

What is the name for the long dashes that sometimes replace the inner letters of a name in older printed texts, and what is their purpose?

[image: Example of long dashes]

[Image source: Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Key_to_Manley_Atalantis_1713.png)

Comment: Interesting that in the first line where they appear ("Dutches of Boujou   D--s M--h") they seem to be set as narrow dashes, or even hyphens.

Comment: The Dash of Pretension, aka the Soupçon of Superciliousness.

Comment: Given that it is likely letterpressed, those very well could just be rules. They may not necessarily translate into a modern ASCII character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As plainclothes has said, the dash is composed of several em-dashes. One might call it a ***long dash***...

> Dickinson is best known for writing brief poems, often untitled, consisting of short lines peppered with long dashes, which mark her out as a more modern voice among her contemporary 19th-century poets. [[Daily Telegraph]](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/booknews/10399471/Complete-Emily-Dickinson-online-archive-goes-live.html)

...or perhaps an *anonymisation dash,* which makes it clear it blanks out most of a name and gives more indication of its length than simply *long*.

The purpose is explained in the Wikipedia article linked to your image, [Roman à clef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_a_clef): it's a crude anonymisation technique.

In the novel, the character called Horatio is identified with the actual Lord Peterborough; and Endymion is fairly obviously Lady Manchester, but it doesn't actually say that.

[This question is perhaps more suited to [ELU.SE](http://english.stackexhange.com/).]

Answer (score 1):

Em dash. It takes up the full body width of the font.